# Limit the key of a HashMap to a specified length of characters

Tags: java, hashmap, hibernate-validator

I would like to limit the size of a key from a hashmap to specific size limit.

I already tried this:

```
@Valid
private Map<Key, String> views;

public class Key {
@NotBlank
@Size(max = 100)
private String key;
```

The problem is that `@Valid` will not valid the key only the value of a hashmap.

What is the best way to limit the key to a specific size of characters?

Comment: Write your own MaxKeyLength annotation and its associated validator, which will simply iterate through the keys of the map and return false if any of them has a key that is too long. Then put this annotation on the views field.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate for the number of characters in your key field (private String key;) in its setter method, if it is greater than the maxLimit, throw some exception.